# View jumps back after setting center in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, timer, ios8, counter

I’m beginner with Xcode, and i have problem with counter in my app.

When i put timer to count points the player(paddle) jump in the place where it was
in first time(in the middle)
 everytime when timer count point.

So what i should do to keep paddle where it is?
Is there something other way to count points?

Its doesnt matter how to control player with swipe or g-sensor, 
but in this example i control it with swipe.
And this problem appears only in ios 8.0> , not in ios 7.

Here some code:

**.h file:**

```
int ScoreNumber;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{   
    IBOutlet UILabel *ScoreLabel;
    NSTimer *Timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIImageView *paddle;    
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint paddleCenterPoint;   
@end
```

**.m file:**

```
@implementation ViewController

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat yPoint = self.paddleCenterPoint.y;
    CGPoint paddleCenter = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, yPoint);

    self.paddle.center = paddleCenter;        
}

-(void)Score{    
    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber +1;
    ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    Timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(Score) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: While this code has several stylistic problems (global variable for score, use of lead-caps in variable names, use of ivars for `ScoreLabel` and `Timer` rather than properties), and fails to `invalidate` the timer when dismissed (so you will get double-scoring if you dismiss the view controller and reload it), I don't see any bugs that would cause the behavior you're describing. I suspect the bug is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I have made test app just for this problem, and i dont have other code in it. Still that happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 8, autolayout is king, and setting `center` doesn't change the layout constraints. This has nothing to do with the timer. It has to do with changing the label's text. When that happens, it triggers a layout of the whole view, and that reasserts the constraints (via `layoutIfNeeded`). Even though you're probably not setting any constraints in IB, Xcode will automatically insert them during the build.

There are several solutions. First, you could insert the paddle programmatically in `viewDidLoad`, which would bypass the constraints system. For this specific problem, that's probably ok (and it might even be how I'd do it personally). Something like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *paddle;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.paddle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50)];
    self.paddle.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.paddle];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    self.paddle.center = CGPointMake(touchLocation.x, self.paddle.center.y);
}    
@end
```

---

But how can we solve this without throwing away constraints? Well, we could just modify the constraint. Add your paddle view in IB, and add constraints for the left, bottom, width, and height. Then create an IB outlet for the horizontal and width constraints.

[image]

Edit the Horizontal Space Constraint to remove "Relative to margin" from both the first and second items:

[image]

Now, you can modify the constraint rather than the center:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *paddle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *paddleHorizontalConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *paddleWidthConstraint;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGFloat width = self.paddleWidthConstraint.constant;

    self.paddleHorizontalConstraint.constant = touchLocation.x - width/2;
}    
@end
```

You need to read the width constraint because the `frame` or `bounds` may not be correct until `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` is called. But you don't want to update the constraint there, since that'll force another layout.